# Multiple if-statements in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have several variables and I would like to validate them before writing them into the mysql database. Basically I would like the following logic: if the username is ok, and the email is ok and the password is ok then write all to the db, else spit out an error for each.

I have tried to come up with the following logic but there must be a more logical and efficient way to do it (sorry, I know this looks primitive):

```
if ( preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/", $username) ) {
    if ((preg_match("^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email)) {
        if (/*password is ok*/) {
            //create user entry in the db
            //and save success message in the session variable
        } else {
            //error message for password
        }
    } else {
        //error message for email
    }
} else {
    //error message for username
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me tbh, although you could avoid nesting the ifs

Comment: So you mean its better to do: if ((username is ok) && (email is ok) && (password is ok)) ?

Comment: Not really because then you can't separate the errors, All your answers have avoided nesting.

Comment: @PartisanEntity I think he means not to include one `if` inside of another `if` block.  Chaining the conditions into a single `if` is okay, but you loose some flexibility that way.

Comment: @watcher: ah thank you got it, i just realised that my code would send the user back with only an error message for the username, if the username failed the validation and would ignore all other validations. I think thats what you mean?

Comment: @PartisanEntity Correct.  It depends on how granular you'd like to be.  If a single 'Validation Failed' error message is okay with you, there's nothing wrong with it, but if you want to tell them what validation failed I would pick a route like one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are lots of frameworks and validation scripts that allow you to do this. On the other hand, it's good to have done this yourself, so you know what is actually going on, should you later decide to switch to a framework.

Your code looks decent, but from a usability point-of-view, it isn't as good as one could have hoped. If I try to create a user in your system, I might have to fill out the forms and press submit several times, which can be quite annoying. Instead, once the form has been filled out, a list of errors should show up, instead of just one error at a time. A common way to handle this problem is by creating an array of error messages.

An implementation could look something like this

```
$errors = array();

if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/", $username))
    array_push($errors, "Invalid username");

if (!preg_match("^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email))
    array_push($errors, "Invalid password");

if (otherValidationRule())
    array_push($errors, "Something else went wrong");
```

After this, you check whether any errors occured and print them if so

```
if (sizeof($errors) > 0) {
    print("<ul>\n");
    foreach($errors as $error)
        printf("<li>%s</li>\n", $error);
    print("</ul>\n");
}
else {
    // Proceed with registration
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. What I have done is used a javascript framework to validate the form which gives immediate feedback and doesn't let them submit until all is well. However, should the user have js turned off, i am planning to run their data through this php validation as well after they click submit.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you'd want to be able to show multiple error messages, in case there was more than one thing wrong. Something like this:

```
$errors = array();
if( !preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/", $username) )
{
    $errors[] = 'Username was invalid';
}
if ((preg_match("^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email))
{
    $errors[] = 'Email was invalid';
}
if( /* Password is bad */ )
{
    $errors[] = 'Password is bad somehow';
}

if( sizeof($errors) == 0 )
{
    // write to db
}
else
{
    // Display all error messages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a shorter and more readable way would be:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/", $username))
    die("username error");

if (!preg_match("^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email))
    die("email error");

if (/*password is NOT ok*/)
    die("password error");

//create user entry in the db
//and save success message in the session variable
```

Notice that I have negated your conditionals so that the contents of the if-statement only execute if a failure occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I may be confused, but i dont think "die" would work in my case because that stops the entire script right? The point is that at the very top of this php script i have the header(); which forwards the user back to the registration form with either an error message or a success message.

Comment: @PartisanEntity: Wait, at the very top of the script, you use `header("Location: xxx.php");`? As soon as you send that header, you can't be sure that the rest of your server-side script will execute. If I'm wrong, and you're not using `header` to redirect at the beginning of the script, then perhaps you would be able to use something like `die(header("Location: xxx.php?error=username"));` and have your registration form create the error message based on `$_GET`.

Comment: @PartisanEntity You're not confused, `die()` indeed isn't such a great solution. In my world, generally `die()` is only justified if it comes right after a redirect.

Comment: @Travesty3 First of all, with your approach, nothing will be printed after. Not even the form that would allow the user to try again, neither would it produce valid HTML mark up, since you're not terminating any of the HTML tags that you have open, e.g. `</body>`.

Comment: @Travesty3: I am in fact using header("Location: index.php"); at the very top of my page, I am storing all my errors and success messages in session variables. I tried placing it later in the page but I keep getting an "output already sent" error even though all i am doing on this page is filling variables and doing the validation.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: A fair point that I didn't clarify at all. I often use `die()` in PHP scripts that will only be called via AJAX (which I thought was a definite possibility for this question). I also wouldn't use it in the middle of the generation of an HTML page, but it works perfectly well in returning a text string to another script, or to a place where HTML is not the result (like command line). Sorry for not clarifying, this is often how I use PHP.

Comment: @PartisanEntity: You get that message because you cannot redirect after headers have already been sent. Most likely, you `echo`ed something before using `header()`. If you tell PHP to redirect at the beginning of your script, you have no guarantee of how much, if any, of the PHP code that follows will be executed, which is why (as @KristianAntonsen pointed out) it is a good idea to `die()` right after a redirect, so your code doesn't unexpectedly execute.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite right. After a redirect, the PHP code will always continue to be executed, unless actively terminated, e.g. using `die()`. Also, it won't be possible to create session variables in conjunction with a header redirect, unless you remember to call `session_write_close()`.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: Thanks for clearing that up. I hadn't thought enough about that to realize that it would always continue executing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use die to end the script

```
if (/*User name in NOT ok*/)
{
die("Bad username");
}

if(/*Password is not ok*/)
{
die("Bad Pass");
}
```

Or use variables

```
$usernameOk = false;
$passwordOk = false;

if(/*Username is ok*/)
{
$username = true;
}

if(/*Password is ok*/)
{
$passwordOk = true;
}

if(/*username true and password true*/)
{
//Execute statement
}
```